# Runtime Error Cannot find module "angular"

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am practicing App development in Ionic 3(Latest Version) and getting the error as follows:

> Runtime Error Cannot find module "angular"

app.module.ts

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { ShoppingListPage } from '../pages/shopping-list/shopping-list';
import { FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS } from './firebase.credentials';

@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ShoppingListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),

    //Initialize AngularFire with credentials from the dashboard
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ShoppingListPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = 'ShoppingListPage';

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

shopping-list.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-shopping-list',
  templateUrl: 'shopping-list.html',
})
export class ShoppingListPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ShoppingListPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you read https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ properly? Are you using a Windows, Mac, other machine... i.e. did you install Node correctly first. Then the Android setup (ios - Mac is a must unless some sort of cloud based setup AFAIK). If you have a Mac homebrew is a good way to get node. nvm is also useful. If you have done all that list your package.json.

Comment: Try `npm install` at project root.